# eclipse avd :emulator error cannot include system.img

Tags: eclipse, adt, android-virtual-device

For the first time on my PC (running Windows 7 Ultimate), I opened Android SDK with Eclipse ADT bundle with everything necessary downloaded. Then I went to avd and did all the settings required, and clicked on 
start it gave me this error

> emulator error cannot include `system.img`

So I went into the directory `E:\soft\Android SDK (ADT Bundle for Windows 32-Bit) + APK Multi-Tool\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\system-images`. There I saw android, clicked on it and I found all the image files
in the same folder. I went to armeabi-v7a, it had everything. 
I searched in Google but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine, after a short coversation with an Android expert, I believe this is a right answer to your question.

There shouldn't be anything wrong with the install path chosen. Make sure you have installed JDK. Version 7 is recommended, but you can use v8.x without problems. Also, read the necessary documents.

There's commentary on the Developers site regarding Eclipse not locating the system images. If you execute Eclipse from its sub-folder in the Tools folder it 
should automatically read the sub directory of system image(s), which is a few folders down from the tools folder. You may need to map the path to the images if Eclipse was run from the desktop, apart from the ADT bundle's hierarchy.

Also consider using the newer Android Studio (in case you still dont get along with Eclipse).

Comment: give me address of the developer site where the answer is located